# Access individual lines of a text file and create separate text file with that name

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two text files (say `text1.txt` and `text 2.txt`) both with same number of lines.
Ex. `text1.txt` contains 4 entries

```
0127H
0132H
0982H
1772H
```

`text2.txt` contains 4 entries

```
stev
mary
beautiful
ugly
```

Now my task is to create 4 text files as

- `0127H.txt` to contain `stev`
- `0132H.txt` to contain `mary`
- `0982H.txt` to contain `beautiful`
- `1772H.txt` to contain `ugly`

I.e. the 1st line of `text1.txt` must be a file name and the corresponding entry will be the 1 st line of `text2.txt`.

I kindly request you to help me to get rid of the issue raised.

Comment: Could you please choose one of the answers as your accepted one?

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`, you can do:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {filename[FNR] = $0 ".txt"} FNR != NR {print > filename[FNR]}' file1 file2
```

- `FNR == NR` tests whether we are reading the first file. If that's the case, we save the line in an array.
- When we read the second file, we lookup the corresponding array value and use that as the output file.

Comment: That *does* work with spaces in the files :-).

Answer (score 2):

The following one-liner will do what you need:

```
bash -c "$(paste text1.txt text2.txt | awk '{print "echo "$2">"$1".txt"}')"
```

Comment: That will create strange files if they contain spaces and if in text2.txt are spaces also.

Comment: You mean since `paste` used tab as a delimiter?

Comment: Indeed, it will put all the words of both files into the same line. It will then use the first word as the name of the file and the second word as the content. This means that if `text1.txt` contains two words or more, everything of `text2.txt` is ignored. – And why did you wrap it in `$(…)`?

Comment: @queueoverflow this version is indeed not ready to work with spaces. About the `$(...)`, it's how I use the the result strings of the `awk` command as inputs to `bash`.

Comment: I see, so the `$(…)` is needed. But that adds another complication layer about the spaces in the file. I have no idea how to quote *that* properly. How come you have the most upvotes with a program that cannot cope with spaces‽

Comment: @queueoverflow: There are many many ways to solve this issue of course :). I proposed an answer based on the OP's sample data.

Comment: The problem with those kind of solutions is that somebody will come along with a file that *does* contain spaces and then it breaks in a non-obvious way. That is what *I* do not want to have in my software.

Answer (score 2):

Another python option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

lines = lambda f: open(f).read().splitlines()
content = lines(sys.argv[2])

for i, item in enumerate(lines(sys.argv[1])):
    open(item+".txt", "wt").write(content[i])
```

This will create the indicated files *in the directory where you run the script from*

- Save it as `combine.py`
- run it with the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/combine.py <file1> <file2>
  ```

---

#### Edit

As suggested by @queueoverflow, using the `zip` option (very neat, even shorter):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

lines = lambda f: open(f).read().splitlines()
for item, content in zip(lines(sys.argv[1]), lines(sys.argv[2])):
    open(item+".txt", "wt").write(content)
```

#### OR

Just for fun; including the `sys.argv[n]` in the lambda function, reducing it a bit further:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

lines = lambda n: open(sys.argv[n]).read().splitlines()
[open(f+".txt", "wt").write(c) for f, c in list(zip(lines(1), lines(2)))]
```

Comment: You can use `for item, content in zip(lines(sys.argv[1]), lines(sys.argv[2]))` and have this even shorter. It won't matter in a short script like this, but that would leak file descriptors when you use `open ()` without a context manager (`with open() as f:`).

Comment: @queueoverflow the zip option is very neat! Thanks for that. About the second remark: it is taken care of during either garbage collection or, in the worst case, at exit.

Comment: Sure, it will be taken care of. It's not like the computer would break because it ran out of file descriptors. I just like it a habit to not write *any* code that leaks *anything* . Your last version looks pretty golfed, but you could make it even shorter by using `open(…).readlines()`, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array) ;-).

Comment: Although I fear that you will end up with `\n` at the end of the files. Now that I think about it, either your filenames have `\n` in them, or you files *lack* `\n` at the end of the lines. This is not a problem since there is only one line in it, but I prefer my files to end with `\n`, so that `cat *.txt` gives reasonable output.

Comment: @queueoverflow splitlines() does not produce any `\n`, reason for me not to use readlines(), even if it makes no difference in practice. Since python3, there is no good reason not to use `open().read()`.  Especially in a case like this, the difference is nihil. Would be interesting to run some `time` tests with huge amounts of data. :)

Comment: The `read()` reads all the lines into memory. What one could improve is to use `for item, content in zip(open(…), open(…)):` since that only reads the lines as needed. This will then work with arbitrary file sizes since it only uses generator expressions.

Comment: @queueoverflow On huge files, the per-line approach would be appropriate, however: I am not sure the discussion is relevant.  You wouldn't want to create (hundreds of-) thousands of files (not to mention millions) in a *flat* directory without corrupting the system (nautilus). I "timed" both scripts on a 1000 lines -file (which is more than OP had in mind I guess), in which the short script above performed repeatedly better than the more verbose one (`r/u/s: 0.082, 0.044,  0.036 against 0.071, 0.047, 0.024`)

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me:

```
c=1; while read f; do sed -n "${c}p" text2.txt >"$f.txt"; ((c++)); done <text1.txt
```

It iterates trough every line in the file `text1.txt`. Then for every line `sed` extracts the corresponding line in the file `text2.txt` and writes it to the that file with `.txt` appended.

Comment: That will break once `f` contains a space. You need to use quotes there: `"$f.txt"`.

Comment: If you seriously want to use Bash, be sure to read the [list of pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). If you think there are to many pitfalls, don't use Bash ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Save the below python script as `files.py` or similar. [You can find it here](https://gist.github.com/martin-ueding/732de53d573d790f2b32)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright © 2015 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de>    
# Licensed under The MIT License

import argparse


def main():

    options = _parse_args()
    with open(options.first) as f:    
        lines1 = [s.strip() for s in f.readlines()]    
    with open(options.second) as f:    
        lines2 = f.readlines()    
    for first, second in zip(lines1, lines2):    
        with open(first + '.txt', 'w') as f:    
            f.write(second)


def _parse_args():    
    '''    
    Parses the command line arguments.            
    :return: Namespace with arguments.    
    :rtype: Namespace    
    '''

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')    
    parser.add_argument('first')    
    parser.add_argument('second')    
    options = parser.parse_args()             
    return options        


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

Then you can start it with

```
python3 files.py text1.txt text2.txt
```

and it will generate all the files you want.

---

Advantages of this solution:

- It works if the lines in the files have spaces or other characters that are treated special in the shell.
- The code is readable without knowing a bunch of [pitfalls in Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).
- In case there are not enough parameter passed on the command line, you will get a readable error message, and calling it with `-h` or `--help` also works just fine.
- It can deal with DOS and Mac OS style line breaks (`\n\r` and `\r`).
- The Python script would even run on Windows.
- It does not leak file descriptors since it uses context managers (`with …:`).

Answer (score 0):

I can do this with the following bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="$1"
count=0
while read LINE
do
  let count++
  sed -n "$count"p text2 > "$LINE".txt
done < "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: You need `$1` instead of `#1` for the first command line argument. And `text2` seems to be fixed, why not use `$2`.

Comment: @queueoverflow That (`#1`) was a typo introduced by me while tidying up the answer. Ron, sorry about that.

Comment: You could just use `done < "$1"` in the last line, no need to introduce another variable. The all capital letter variables are usually only used for environment variables (like `PATH` or `EDITOR`). When you write a shell script, you can just use lowercase variable names, like you did with `count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `bash`:

```
IFS=$'\n'
a=($(<text1.txt))
i=0
while read -r line; do
  echo "${line}" > "${a[i++]}"
done < text2.txt
```

The `IFS` assignment tells `bash` to treat only newline as the word delimiter. If you don't want that setting to affect you'r running shell, you might want to launch a new `bash` instance for all of this, or reset `IFS` afterwards to its default using `IFS=$' \t\n'`.

The next line has two parts. `a=( 0127H 0132H 0982H 1772H )` would make `a` an array with four entries. But instead of listing the entries verbatim, we substitute the content of the file in there. `$(…)` usually executes a command and expands to its output, but with a leading `<` in there it behaves almost as if the command were `cat`, i.e. it expands to the content of that file. The output of that file is split into words accoring to `IFS`, so lines containing whitespace end up in a single array element.

Then we loop over the lines of `text2.txt`, and use the counter `i` to identify the matching element of `text1.txt`. We could also load `text2.txt` as an array, and then iterate over both array in parallel, particularly after verifying that their lengths agree.

```
IFS=$'\n'
a=($(<text1.txt))
b=($(<text2.txt))
if [[ ${#a[@]} -ne ${#b[@]} ]]; then
  echo "Length mismatch" >& 2
else
  for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; ++i)); do
    echo "${b[i]}" > "${a[i]}"
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at this task:

Step 1 - create a list of all the text files you want to have one word. Named mine `list`, and one perline listed text1, text2, text3, and text4

Step 2 - Create list of words , one per line. Mine is named `word`

Step 3 - run the following command: `pr -m -t words list | awk '{x=$2; print $1>x}'`

Now, of course, it's not a one-liner, but worked for me. My word list was `one two three four`, and now text1 has `one`, text2 has `two`, and so forth

**Edit**:

Here's my crude attempt at addressing spaces between words in words file: translate `\n` to another character and then using that character as delimiter in awk. I've tested this with 
`df | tr '\n' '@' |  awk -F '@' '{for (i=1;i<5;i++) print $i > "file"i".txt" }'`

The result is that  I got 4 different files, with 4 consecutive lines from `df` command. Substitute `df` with `cat words`. Here's the result

[image]

And yes, this method isn't perfect; what if a line contains `@` in the middle of it or at the end. But this method is flexible - `@` can be substituted with something else. In addition user should probably be aware when trying to process text files how they are delimited; good example is `/etc/passwd`, where fields are separated by `:` , and no one blindly charged into processing that file, right ?

Comment: I think that will break with spaces in the words as well.

Comment: @queueoverflow yes, if there's two words separated by spaces on same line, that will break.  OP showed his expected behavior in the question, and that's what I achieved.

Comment: Given the way the question was posed, I do not see awareness for the troubles that spaces might bring when implementing this with shell scripts. Therefore I assume that the OP just gave a minimal example which does not contain spaces for simplicity, not because he/she is sure that there never will be spaces. I got burned with software not coping with spaces often enough myself, so I try my best to make new software cope with spaces well.

Comment: addressed spaces in lines , please reffer

Comment: Using null (`\0`) as a field delimiter be a bit less arbitrary, programs like `find -print0` use this as a delimiter, and `xargs -0` can read those. Since `\0` is illegal for names in the filesystem, I think, this is fine for filenames. In a text file, you can have `\0`, I think, so that *might* break. Also you replace `\n` with your symbol. Couldn't you use that as a delimiter in `awk` directly? And if you have a file with DOS or Mac OS line breaks (`\n\r` and `\r`), it will not work. Your filenames are now just numbered instead of using the words in the second file. Did I miss something?